# I have a dataset. How do I convert this data into Indifference Curves?

Tags: microeconomics

This is all hypothetical. I understand indifference curves. However, I don't understand how they are produced. I read this question, and the survey answer made sense to me...

[Research Design: Indifference curves and budget lines](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/research-design-indifference-curves-and-budget-lines)

I read this paper...

http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hal/Papers/2005/revpref.pdf

It talks about creating indifference curves from prices individuals are willing to pay for certain goods, household budgets, and time series data from aggregate consumption.

So, if I had a list of prices that individuals would be willing to pay for a unit of bread, and I had a list of prices that various individuals would be willing to pay for a unit of kale, how would I find the points for an indifference curve?

If I had household budgets where I saw how much each household paid for x units of bread, and y units of kale, how would I find the points for indifference curves?

Finally, if I had a list of years, and the quantities consumed of bread and kale in a region. How would I find the points for the relevant indifference curves?